# C# WebBrowser isn't loading a page

Tags: c#, javascript, visual-studio-2010, webbrowser-control, webgl

Well, I've a problem, when I try to navigate to a webGL page using the Webbrowser component, I see a blank page, meaning the page isn't loading.

The page contains WebGL and Javascript, so I think maybe webbrowser doesn't support one or both of those. I've also tried to use gecko, but it didn't work, either.

Note that I'm using C# in Visual Studio 13.

Anyone can help me?? Thanks for all ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have IE11 installed on the PC in question, and you need to set the registry key FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION to IE11 mode for `yourapp.exe` and `yourapp.vshost.exe`

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee330730%28VS.85%29.aspx#browser_emulation